# Can (nonsense) mean (in vain)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice

> The king asked his servants and guards to search for a truly happy man in the kingdom *but nonsense*, there was no single happy man in the kingdom.

Shouldn't **(nonsense)** be replaced by **(in vain)** in the previous sentence, unless it has the meaning of (in vain)?

Comment: Your study book is probably of very low quality. I see you also asked on Wordreference.com.

Comment: That's true, the book is really of low quality. I'm struggling to understand its texts.
But it's my school book and I have no choice but to study it.

Comment: What is its title?

Comment: Emar. It's an English series.

Comment: Here, "But nonsense" reads like an interjection, rather than an adverbial. It sounds as if the servants or the story's narrator are commenting on how impossible the task is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In vain" has a shade of a different meaning to "nonsense".

Nonsense is basically "no sense" as in "it makes no sense".

> The king asked his servants and guards to search for a truly happy man in the kingdom

This makes no sense because there would be no truly happy man in the kingdom. In other words, it is a futile search, that **makes no sense**.

To replace it with "in vain" suggest that this is a sensible search but in this particular kingdom no such man could be found.

As a clearer example, imagine the king asked to search for "a man with three legs". You wouldn't search "in vain" for such a man, because the search itself is nonsense. No such man would exist, searching for him or not.

> Can (nonsense) mean (in vain)?

No.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Now, it makes clear indeed.

Comment: You could say, perfectly correctly, that a search for e.g. a flying dog, or a man with three hands, would be in vain. That is because if an action is in vain, it is 'without success or a result'. The fact that common sense says that the item being searched for cannot exist does not affect that.

Comment: Yes, but "in vain" and "nonsense" are not synonyms. I might search in vain for my car keys, but it wouldn't be a nonsensical search. I might reasonably expect to find them. However searching for a flying dog, albeit in vain, fails for the reason that the search is nonsense, not that the flying dog is perhaps somewhere else.